# Is this python-click behaviour correct?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I am trying to use Pallets Click to make a command line program that takes a list of input parameters and one optional output parameter.

Same behavior on both Ubuntu 18.04 Python 3.6 and Windows 10 Python 3.7 with python-click version 7.0.

I made a test file `click_test.py`:

```py
import click


@click.command()
@click.argument('src', nargs=-1, required=True)
@click.argument('dst', required=False)
def copy(src, dst):
    print(f'{src!r}')
    print(f'{dst!r}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    copy()
```

Running `python click_test.py first-argument` give this output:

```
Usage: click_test.py [OPTIONS] SRC... [DST]
Try "click_test.py --help" for help.

Error: Missing argument "SRC...".
```

The usage description describes what I am expecting. SRC is required, but DST is optional. But still, the error message says missing SRC.

It this correct behavior, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Your desired command line is a bit ambiguous. How would click know when a `src` was a `src` or the last `dst`?  So with the `nargs=-1` the parser defers the value from `src` to `dst`.

However, the expectation in your question, can be achieved with a bit of re-plumbing in the form of a custom `click.Argument` class.

#### Custom Class:

```
def take_empty_from(other_param_name):

    class EmptyFrom(click.Argument):

        def consume_value(self, ctx, opts):
            value = opts.get(self.name)
            if value == () and opts.get(other_param_name):
                value = opts[self.name] = (opts.get(other_param_name), )
                opts[other_param_name] = None
                return value
            else:
                return super(EmptyFrom, self).consume_value(ctx, opts)

    return EmptyFrom
```

#### Using the Custom Class:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('src', nargs=-1, required=True, cls=take_empty_from('dst'))
@click.argument('dst', required=False)
def copy(src, dst):
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.argument()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Argument` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Argument` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case, we override `click.Argument.consume_value()` and then in the case of only one parameter grab the argument from `dst` and put it into `src`.

Note: that while this behavior meets the request in the question, it still leaves unanswered why `src` is only un-needed when there is a single `dst` parameter.

#### Test Code:

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.argument('src', nargs=-1, required=True, cls=take_empty_from('dst'))
@click.argument('dst', required=False)
def copy(src, dst):
    click.echo('src: {}'.format(src))
    click.echo('dst: {}'.format(dst))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '',
        'a',
        'a b',
        'a b c',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            copy(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
-----------
> 
Usage: click_prog.py [OPTIONS] SRC... [DST]

Error: Missing argument "src".
-----------
> a
src: ('a',)
dst: None
-----------
> a b
src: ('a',)
dst: b
-----------
> a b c
src: ('a', 'b')
dst: c
-----------
> --help
Usage: click_prog.py [OPTIONS] SRC... [DST]

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Thank you @StephenRauch for your comprehensive answer. I does indeed solve my use case.

Regarding the question if this is a bug or not, I am not satisfied. The  [Click documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/arguments/?highlight=variadic#variadic-arguments) on Variadic Arguments states:

_Note that only one argument can be set to nargs=-1, as it will eat up all arguments._